# How can I store messages in a JMS Queue without using a Database?

Tags: queue, jms, message-driven-bean, message-listener

I have sent messages to a JMS Queue using a Servlet;
and there is Message Listener for that Queue
but I m not using those messages anywhere;
but when I check the Messages in the Queue using WebLogic Admin console; it is not displaying any messages although it is indicating that there are 20 messages in Total.
Kindly tell me what I can do to save the sent messages in the JMS Queue??
Any guidance or suggestion would be highly appreciable.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not WebLogic expert but generally speaking:

**The messages are saved by a JMS provider till they are consumed. So you don't need to do anything to save those message in a JMS queue.**

It is possible that the message listener has already consumed those messages and the Admin Console is showing "Total messages processed" and not currently available messages?

**Update**

Sample for sending persistent messages. Set the DeliverMode as PERSISTENT. All message sent using this producer will be Persistent.

```
            // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
            Destination destination = session.createQueue("TESTQ");

            // Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            // We want persistent messages
            producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
```

Comment: so, any idea how I can save those message in the Queue ;I don't wanna consume those messages; just want them to be inside the Queue ??

Comment: Looks like I was not clear earlier. Let me reiterate: Once an application sends a message successfully to a JMS Provider, WebLogic in your case, the message is saved by JMS Provider (WebLogic here) till they are received by a consumer. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: @Shashi Only if the message is PERSISTENT, otherwise, if the provider crashes, messages in memory will be lost; PERSISTENT messages are stored on disk by default.

Comment: True. Since the question did not mention about JMS provider crashing, I did not mention that point.

Comment: Sashi and @raffian Thank you for helpful response;
Now kindly tell me;   
if I use a Message Driven Bean with a queue but I don't link that MDB with any consumer; still they are getting lost..... I wanna know WHY??      
and the second question is HOW to make messages persistent??

Comment: Don't know the answer to 1st question. But see the update for sample on how to make messages persistent.

Comment: @user3462765 the MDB is a consumer, so as long as it's listening to the queue, messages will be consumed from the queue; disable the MDB and only send to the queue, the messages will then remain on the queue

Comment: Okie One more question; Is there any way I can pre store messages into a Queue using Admin Console;   
and don't need to send them to Queue in order to store them into Queue. Thank you!